# Call Kaggle API without multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, kaggle

I noticed that the Kaggle API uses multithreading to fetch data. This has been causing problems for me and I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to use the API sequentially. I'm fairly new to multithreading, hopefully this makes sense and isn't completely stupid.

[Source code from Kaggle](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/blob/master/kaggle/api_client.py#L85)

Comment: It uses a `ThreadPool`, which the name implies uses threads under the hood, not multiprocessing

Comment: Thanks, updated question

Comment: Set `async_req` on `call_api` to False.

Comment: `async_req` defaults to `None`, so it shouldn't be being used.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized the problem was occurring when I invoke `ThreadPool` and so when I commented that out it worked fine.